# Overflowing the return result for compareTo?

Tags: java, compareto

Is there a potential for overflow if I were to write the following:

```
 public class SomeObj implements Comparable<SomeObj> {

    private final float data;

    public SomeObj(float data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

    public int compareTo(SomeObj object) {
       return (int) (this.data - object.data);
    }

 }
```

I've seen other Java developers write their `compareTo` methods like how I did above as a shortcut instead of writing a bunch of `if-else` statements. Would the latter be the best approach to implementing the `compareTo` method here if there really is a potential for overflow?

Comment: Why on earth not `Float.compare(this.data, object.data)`? I think all the primitive types have comparators like this, at least.

Comment: @sverre: Annoyingly, Integer didn't get one until Java 7 :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely *not* write `compareTo` methods like this:

- It will fail if you have `this.data = 0.5f` and `object.data = 0.2f` for example - presumably that should return a positive value, but it will return 0
- It could overflow the range of `int` (I can't even remember what Java does in that case, offhand - casting in such a situation is almost always the wrong approach, so I don't usually *need* to remember)
- For similar situations with `int`, you can end up subtracting a positive number from a negative number and getting a large *positive* number due to overflow

I'm sure I could think of other nasty situations with enough effort.

Fortunately, the fix is easy:

```
return Float.compare(this.data, object.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very good reason, I would use `double` instead of `float` to minimise representation error (by a factor of 9 digits!)  In an object, using `float` might not even save any memory.

As such I would use which works whether you use a `float` or a `double` or an `int` for that matter.

```
public int compareTo(SomeObj object) {
   return Double.compare(data, object.data);
}
```